# Right approach to test convert-like methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Suppose i have lots of classes like this (Foo1, Foo2 ..)

```
class Foo 
{
    public int F{get; set;}

    public Bar ConvertToBar ()
    {
        return new Bar(){ B = this.F*10 };
    }
}
```

all they have in common is ConvertToBar() method.

I have two approaches to unit-test this method:

1. Call convert to ConvertToBar () and check all it's properties (I have to do it in all tests for each Foo like class)

   Bar bar = foo.ConvertToBar ();
    Assert.AreEqual (expectedValue, bar.Property);
   ...
2. Write helper method that compares two Bar instances and then use it like this:

   Bar expectedBar = new Bar ()
   Assert.True( barCompareMethod (expectedBar, foo.ConvertToBar ());

What will be the best way to write unit-test for this method?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046121/how-to-compare-two-object-in-unit-test-how-to-compare-two-collection-in-unit-tes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it make sense for `Bar` itself to be `IEquatable<Bar>`? If so, I'd implement that in your production code, rather than having a helper method. Then you can just use `Assert.AreEqual(expectedBar, actualBar)`.

Comment: And, what do you think about if it makes sense the effort of implementing `IEquatable<T>` in all classes subject of testing conversions? It'd be a nightmare!

Comment: +1 I always go for IEquatable myself, but see my answer for how to handle cases where that isn't appropriate or possible.

Comment: @Orsol: Then implementing `IEqualityComparer<Bar>` would make sense - or possibly just creating a helper method, as you suggest. In fact, the helper method could be an AssertBarEquals method that would indicate where they differed.

Comment: @Matías: Well, it's the target of the conversions that's important here... and the OP says he's only got one target type. I find that the targets of conversions are typically the kinds of type where it's useful to have equality anyway.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I'm agreed, it's just an advice for the author because maybe this is a limited example and he needs to think what's going on if it takes 'IEquatable<T>' approach :)

Answer (score 4):

As Jon Skeet suggests, implementing custom equality on Bar is a great idea as long as you understand how to steer clear of [Equality Pollution](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Logic%20in%20Production.html#Equality%20Pollution).

For semantic comparison, you can use [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/)'s SemanticComparison library, which would enable you to write a assertion like this:

```
var expected = bar1.AsSource().OfLikeness<Bar>();
expected.ShouldEqual(bar2);
```

The ShouldEqual method is a custom assertion that will compare each property (matched by name) and only succeed when all properties are equal; otherwise it will throw a descriptive exception.

Comment: I'm not question's author, but I honestly believe this is the right solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is a best way.

- the first is a bit more readable in my opinion. You may want to experiment with [NUnit's property constaints](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=propertyConstraint&r=2.4.7)

  Assert.That(someObject, Has.Property("Version").EqualTo("2.0"));
- the second is a bit more work in that you'd have to define Equals in the Bar classes (might be a problem if you do not have source edit access). But it would be preferable, if a large number of properties need to be asserted on.

Comment: Personally I find that for performing a simple equality test, the property constraint is much less readable than a simple Assert.AreEqual test. I know some people love it, but I'm not a fan myself...

Comment: @Jon - True. I was answering to the example in the Question. If an object has n properties, out of which only 1 or 2 are relevant in the context of the current test, I prefer constraints or matchers because they tend to highlight the change. If a majority of the properties are relevant, then I agree that the equality method approach wins.. I'm experimenting with Hamcrest matchers as of now.. so might be posting under the influence :)

Comment: I was meaning a simple `Assert.AreEqual("2.0", someObject.Version)` instead of using the `Has.Property` syntax. I've never been much of a fan of Hamcrest either ;)

Comment: @Jon - To quote Homer simpson "DOH!" :) I just instantly lost faith in Has.Property.. even `AssertThat(someObject.Version, Equals("2.0"))` is better.